# How to get Elevation details for Current GPS coordinates in Android

Tags: android

In my android application i am getting current GPS longitude and lattitude details perfectly by using LocationManager class

I observed that we can easily get Altitude details also but in my application i want **Elevation** details of Current GPS location.

Can any one tell me how can i get **Elevation** details for a current gps location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to use the google maps [elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/). You can use it to obtain elevation information for any coordinate pair. Also check the [Gmaps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) documentation.